# I want to know how to pray with urine incontinence

Tags: wudu, incontinence

I know that I have urine incontinence but the problem is I also have vaginal discharge. I don't know if I am a mazoor or not because I can't differentiate between urine or discharge. So I just do wudu for each Salah and pray. Am I doing the right thing?